# How to interpolate and extract points above loess smooth in R?

Tags: r, performance, linear-interpolation, loess

(This post is the second half of the problem from: [How to apply loess.smoothing to both plot and then extract points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583975/how-to-apply-loess-smoothing-to-both-plot-and-then-extract-points))

I have plotted loess smoothing to a scatterplot (i.e. between two quantitative variables). I would like to extract only the data points in the scatterplot that are above that smoothing line.

For instance, if this is my scatterplot:

```
qplot(mpg, cyl, data=mtcars)
```

I can plot the smoother as:

```
qplot(hp,wt,data=mtcars) + stat_smooth(method="loess")
```

Now, I want to extract only the data points that are above the smoother. I have played with code provided in ([Method to extract stat_smooth line fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789871/method-to-extract-stat-smooth-line-fit/9790803#9790803)):

```
model <- loess(wt ~ hp, data=mtcars)
xrange <- range(mtcars$hp)
xseq <- seq(from=xrange[1], to=xrange[2], length=80)
pred <- predict(model, newdata = data.frame(hp = xseq), se=TRUE)
y = pred$fit
ci <- pred$se.fit * qt(0.95 / 2 + .5, pred$df)
ymin = y - ci
ymax = y + ci
loess.DF <- data.frame(x = xseq, y, ymin, ymax, se = pred$se.fit)
```

This results in a data frame loess.DF of 80 rows and 5 columns.

I know now that I must apply a function to go through each row of the original mtcars data frame, and interpolate for each x-value (hp) its closest predicted loess y-value (wt). My only idea to accomplish this interpolation is to use a linear interpolation similar to (http://www.ajdesigner.com/phpinterpolation/linear_interpolation_equation.php). After that, I would simply compare the y-value in mtcars with the interpolated predicted loess y-value. If the y-value in mtcars is larger than the predicted loess y-value, then I keep that original data point; else, I remove it.

I started to code this, but realize that I cannot do so in an efficient way. One problem is that my (real) data set (which isn't mtcars) is very large (~40,000 rows): First, to do the linear interpolation, I need to find the two x values in the loess fit that are closest to the original x value in my data set (if there isn't exactly one perfect match), and I do not know how to do that efficiently without searching through increasing loess x-values.

How is an efficient way to approach this, for example, testing it out first on the mtcars data set? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this automatically as the `residuals` list component returned by `loess`:

```
> str(model)
List of 17
 $ n        : int 32
 $ fitted   : num [1:32] 2.83 2.83 2.57 2.83 3.74 ...
 $ residuals: Named num [1:32] -0.2133 0.0417 -0.2477 0.3817 -0.2997 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
 $ enp      : num 4.94
 $ s        : num 0.655
 $ one.delta: num 26.1
 $ two.delta: num 25.8
 $ trace.hat: num 5.43
 $ divisor  : num 1
...
```

If you do: `model$residuals`, positive values are above the line and negative lines are below:

```
> which(sign(model$residuals) == 1)
      Mazda RX4 Wag      Hornet 4 Drive             Valiant           Merc 240D            Merc 230            Merc 280 
                  2                   4                   6                   8                   9                  10 
          Merc 280C          Merc 450SE  Cadillac Fleetwood Lincoln Continental   Chrysler Imperial            Fiat 128 
                 11                  12                  15                  16                  17                  18 
   Dodge Challenger         AMC Javelin    Pontiac Firebird       Maserati Bora 
                 22                  23                  25                  31
```

The above result is all points from the original data that are above the LOESS curve.