# ggplot2 in R: fill underneath a geom_smooth line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to fill in a portion of a plot underneath a `geom_smooth()` line.

Example:

[image: An example of a fill under a curve.]

In the example the data fits on that curve. My data is not as smooth. I want to use `geom_point()` and a mix of `geom_smooth()` and `geom_area()` to fill in the area under the smoothed line while leaving the points above.

A picture of my data with a `geom_smooth()`:

[image: Male points are blue, female points are red.]

In other words, I want everything underneath that line to be filled in, like in Image 1.

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) for your graph? That would make it much easier for others to assist you.

Comment: I will next time. Thanks for the suggestion. @shreyasgm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `predict` with the type of smoothing being used. `geom_smooth` uses `loess` for n < 1000 and `gam` for n > 1000.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth() +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0,ymax = predict(loess(hwy ~ displ))),
                alpha = 0.3,fill = 'green')
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: But let's say that I wanted to fill based on gender. Here is [my data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5poh0gpoq0wa4du/AABMmRpObK9fv7Xy7HzaC-QYa?dl=0). I want to create two different `geom_smooth`s, and fill under each with blue or red, like my points in the new graph in the question. I want points only under the blue line or only under the red line to have those colors, and everything under both lines to be purple. Thanks!

Comment: That's an interesting question! Please post it as a separate question with a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) instead of editing your original question - the answer is involved. You'll find some pointers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789871/method-to-extract-stat-smooth-line-fit) though.

Comment: I'm newish to Stack Overflow, so thanks for the formatting suggestions. Here is the [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368778/use-geom-ribbon-for-shading-under-two-different-geom-smooth-lines). Thank you!