# How can I get the data behind the curve of ggplot2::geom_smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam

take this example :

```
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Width,Sepal.Length)) + geom_smooth()
```

How do I get the `x` and `y` that were used to plot this blue curve ?

This case will be computed by `loess` automatically, my real case is computed by `gam` automatically.

I tried :

- reproducing it with `gam` function
- exploring the plot object

And didn't have success with any

Comment: give an example of your gam model for the data you use, in which package gam function is included?

Comment: have you looked here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789871/method-to-extract-stat-smooth-line-fit

Comment: yes it's a duplicate indeed, many thanks!

Comment: tldr `ggplot_build(my_plot)$data[[1]][c("x","y")]`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood the question, try this approach:

```
 library(gam)
    library(broom)
    mod <- gam(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width,  data = iris)
    ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width,Sepal.Length)) + geom_point() + 
      geom_line(data = augment(mod, type.predict = "response"), 
                aes(y = .fitted), color = "blue")
```