# R loess prediction does not match ggplot geom_smooth(). Error in my prediction formula?

Tags: r, ggplot2, loess

I am trying to predict, on my own, the loess values provided by ggplot `geom_smooth()`. I have attached links to my data and the output plot of the predictions.

Data can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/do4nrkqqjc01na1/data5a.RData?dl=0). I followed an example provided from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789871/method-to-extract-stat-smooth-line-fit) about loess prediction to reproduce the values from ggplot, so I think I am on the right track, but I am missing something.

```
library("ggplot2")
load(file="data5a.RData")
lsmod = loess(Flux~DA_SQ_KM, data=data5a, control=loess.control(surface="direct"))
xrange <- max(data5a$DA_SQ_KM,na.rm=TRUE)
xseq <- c(0.01,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,seq(from=1, to=xrange, length=100))
pred = predict(lsmod,newdata=data.frame(DA_SQ_KM = xseq), se=TRUE)
y = pred$fit
ci <- pred$se.fit * qt(0.95 / 2 + .5, pred$df)
ymin = y - ci
ymax = y + ci
loess.DF <- data.frame(x = xseq, y, ymin, ymax, se = pred$se.fit)

ggplot(data5a, aes(DA_SQ_KM, Flux)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="loess")+
  geom_smooth(aes_auto(loess.DF), data=loess.DF, stat="identity",col="red")+
  geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,col="green")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  scale_y_log10()+
  scale_x_log10()
```

Where is the error in my code for reproducing the data in the blue curve that is predicted by `geom_smooth()`?

Here is an image of the output within ggplot:

[image: Output ggplot image]

**UPDATE 1:**

I have included updated code here based on input provided by Roland. I have modified my code to use the `mgcv::gam` function since my data contains greater than 1000 points. The issue still remains that I cannot reproduce the model created by `geom_smooth` within ggplot. A new issue has also emerged with the confidence intervals.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("mgcv")
load(file="data5a.RData")

#Attempt to re-create the gam model myself
gammod = mgcv::gam(Flux~s(DA_SQ_KM, bs = "cs"),data=data5a)

xrange <- max(data5a$DA_SQ_KM,na.rm=TRUE)
xseq <- c(0.001,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,seq(from=1, to=xrange, length=100))

pred = predict(gammod ,newdata=data.frame(DA_SQ_KM = xseq), se=TRUE)
y = pred$fit
ci <- pred$se.fit * qt(0.95 / 2 + .5, pred$df)
ymin = y - ci
ymax = y + ci
gam.DF <- data.frame(x = xseq, y, ymin, ymax, se = pred$se.fit)


ggplot(data5a, aes(DA_SQ_KM, Flux)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(aes_auto(gam.DF), data=gam.DF, stat="identity",col="red")+
  stat_smooth(method=mgcv::gam,formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"),se=TRUE,col="purple")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  scale_y_log10()+
  scale_x_log10()
```

Here is the gam output within ggplot:

[image: Output2 ggplot image]

Comment: It looks like you might have more than 1000 observations. In such a case, `stat_smooth` does not use `loess` but `mgcv::gam`.

Comment: Roland, thank you for pointing that out. I have modified my code accordingly and included an update to my post. The issue still remains however that I cannot seem to reproduce the predictions from ggplot `geom_smooth` with my own gam model.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Within my post I have include the link to the dataset [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/do4nrkqqjc01na1/data5a.RData?dl=0) and it should be completely reproducible including the creation of the figure.

Comment: Sorry, I don't download data from dropbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ggplot2 fits the model to the transformed variables if you use `scale_*` transformations:

```
DF <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c(10, 100, 1e3))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(DF, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", n = 3)
g <- ggplot_build(p)
g[["data"]][[2]]
#  x y ymin ymax se PANEL group  colour   fill size linetype weight alpha
#1 1 1    1    1  0     1    -1 #3366FF grey60    1        1      1   0.4
#2 2 2    2    2  0     1    -1 #3366FF grey60    1        1      1   0.4
#3 3 3    3    3  0     1    -1 #3366FF grey60    1        1      1   0.4
```

Note the zero SEs, which indicate a perfect fit.

```
log10(predict(lm(y ~ x, data = DF)))
#  1        2        3 
#NaN 2.568202 2.937016 

predict(lm(log10(y) ~ x, data = DF))
#1 2 3 
#1 2 3
```

Comment: Roland, thanks. I see the problem now. I thought `scale_*` simply transformed my axes and not my data.