# How do I smooth data whilst giving out the smoothed data values into a new data frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, plotly

I have a set of data which I've re-sampled, is there a command of a function that I can use in R to smooth the data first, and only then create the graph from the created data frame?.

My data has a lot of noise, an after I've re-sampled the data, now I want to smooth out the data, I used the `geom_smooth` to produce a graphic of the data, but the command only creates the graphical representation of the smoothed out data, without giving out the values of the points it represented.

```
use ggplot
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

df <- read.csv("data.csv", header = T)

str(df)

rs <- sample_n(df,715)

q <- 
  ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", formula = y~log(x), span = 0.05)
```

This is what I used to smooth out my data, I used loess, formula = y~log(x), span = 0.05 because out of all the smoothing out method I've tried, this is the closest result to what I want which is smoothing with the least errors or differences from the original data.

this is a printout of the `head(rs)` and `glimpse(rs)`

```
> head(rs)
        Date  DLTime   Time24   RH Temp PM2.5     CO2    MCO2 MPM25                   t
1 21/05/2019 8:33:21 15:21:36 73.5 25.9    34 1096.88 1096.88    34 2019-05-21 15:21:36
2 21/05/2019 8:56:33 15:44:48 75.4 25.6    32  975.00  975.00    32 2019-05-21 15:44:48
3 21/05/2019 8:22:43 15:10:58 75.9 26.1    59 1068.75 1068.75    59 2019-05-21 15:10:58
4 21/05/2019 8:51:53 15:40:08 74.7 25.6    45  975.00  975.00    45 2019-05-21 15:40:08
5 21/05/2019 8:47:30 15:35:45 75.0 25.7    40 1006.25 1006.25    40 2019-05-21 15:35:45
6 21/05/2019 8:35:59 15:24:14 73.7 25.8    32 1984.38 1068.75    32 2019-05-21 15:24:14
> glimpse(rs)
Observations: 715
Variables: 10
$ Date   <fct> 21/05/2019, 21/05/2019, 21/05/2019, 21/05/2019, 21/05/2019, 21/05/2019, 21/05/2019, 21/05/2019,...
$ DLTime <fct> 8:33:21, 8:56:33, 8:22:43, 8:51:53, 8:47:30, 8:35:59, 8:17:13, 8:57:42, 8:20:34, 8:48:21, 8:34:...
$ Time24 <fct> 15:21:36, 15:44:48, 15:10:58, 15:40:08, 15:35:45, 15:24:14, 15:05:28, 15:45:57, 15:08:49, 15:36...
$ RH     <dbl> 73.5, 75.4, 75.9, 74.7, 75.0, 73.7, 76.6, 75.1, 75.6, 75.1, 74.4, 75.6, 73.8, 76.6, 73.9, 76.3,...
$ Temp   <dbl> 25.9, 25.6, 26.1, 25.6, 25.7, 25.8, 26.2, 25.6, 26.1, 25.7, 25.9, 25.8, 25.4, 26.2, 25.5, 26.2,...
$ PM2.5  <int> 34, 32, 59, 45, 40, 32, 42, 34, 35, 45, 36, 33, 29, 42, 46, 36, 42, 33, 35, 33, 39, 32, 39, 35,...
$ CO2    <dbl> 1096.88, 975.00, 1068.75, 975.00, 1006.25, 1984.38, 1328.13, 946.88, 1068.75, 1328.13, 1434.38,...
$ MCO2   <dbl> 1096.88, 975.00, 1068.75, 975.00, 1006.25, 1068.75, 1037.50, 946.88, 1068.75, 1021.88, 1112.50,...
$ MPM25  <dbl> 34, 32, 59, 45, 40, 32, 42, 34, 35, 45, 36, 33, 29, 42, 46, 36, 42, 33, 35, 33, 39, 32, 39, 35,...
$ t      <dttm> 2019-05-21 15:21:36, 2019-05-21 15:44:48, 2019-05-21 15:10:58, 2019-05-21 15:40:08, 2019-05-21...
```

I have also tried

```
ml <- with(rs, loess(formula = y~log(x), span = 0.5))

mp <- predict(ml)
```

but it resulted in this error message

```
ml <- loess(formula = y~log(x), with(rs), span = 0.5)
Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  argument is missing, with no default
```

I dont really understand where I went wrong, because any troubleshooting I've done through the internet didn't really gave me a definitive answer. If there are other methods, please do tell me.

I apologize for not giving a reproducible example, I am not far enough into learning R that I can create a random data, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789871/method-to-extract-stat-smooth-line-fit

Comment: try `loess(formula = y~log(x), data=rs, span = 0.5)`

Answer (score 1):

These two lines are not the same:

```
ml <- with(rs, loess(formula = y~log(x), span = 0.5))

ml <- loess(formula = y~log(x), with(rs), span = 0.5)
```

I've tested the first one without any trouble (using some faked data). The second one fails because you haven't given `with()` an expression to evaluate.

This also works with a similar structure to the second command you provided, but seems a bit pointless:

```
ml <- loess(formula = y~log(x), with(rs, rs), span = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, the `loess` function does the same thing as the `geom_smooth(method = "loess")` in smoothing the data, then when the model is passed to the `predict` function you get a vector of the new dependent variables. You can plot these on a graph to check:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

a <- rnorm(100)
b <- rnorm(100, mean = 4, sd = 20)*a

df <- tibble(a,b)

df_predict <- df[,"a"]

df_predict[,"b"] <- df %>%
  loess(b ~ a, data = ., span = 0.5) %>% 
  predict()

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(a,b)) +
  geom_point(col = "blue") +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.5, col = "red") +
  geom_point(data = df_predict, col = "red")

df_predict

# A tibble: 100 x 2
        a       b
    <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  0.116   0.502
 2  0.870  -3.44 
 3  0.336   1.16 
 4 -1.16   -9.32 
 5  1.73    8.88 
 6  0.236   0.756
 7  0.485   0.302
 8 -1.13   -9.58 
 9 -0.778 -10.1  
10 -2.76   11.9  
# ... with 90 more rows
```

This gives the following graph, with the raw data plotted in blue, the red line from the `geom_smooth` function and the red dots from the `loess` formula using `predict` to give the `df_predict` dataframe:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Considering I only needed to know the smooth value of one variable, I used:

#smoothing out only one variable
ml <- loess(formula = rs$MCO2~log(rs$Num),  span = 0.5)

#predicting the values of the smooth data
mp <- predict(ml)

#insert predicted data values into resampled data frame
rs$pre <- mp

I added a new column to my data consisting of a number series of my data (1-the end), so I can insert my data into the `y~log(x)` formula, because when I entered the `t` variable which is a `as.POSIXct` date and time argument, it resulted in an error.

To keep the values of the predicted data, I used:

write.csv(rs,"newdata.csv", row.names = FALSE)

Thank you for all the help and anwers.

@Andrew Baxter
@S Robidoux
@Jon Spring
@Jimbou
```

Comment: I did this because stack keeps saying "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon." and for the life of me I cannot figure out where my format is wrong